# Push a static associative element into all subarrays on a known level with a known parent key

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have a dynamically generated PHP multi-dimensional array as follows:

```
Array (
    [uid_1] => Array (
        [sub_1] => Array (
            [sub_sub_1] => Array (
                [id1] => "val_1",
                [id2] => "val_2"
            )
        )
        [sub_2] => Array (
            [sub_sub_1] => Array (
                [id1] => "val_1",
                [id2] => "val_2"
            ),
            [sub_sub_2] => Array (
                [id3] => "val_3",
                [id4] => "val_4"
            )
        )
    )
)
```

The array is much bigger and will contain multiple [uid], [sub] and [sub_sub].
Note that while [uid] and [sub] are unique, [sub_sub] are not.

Is it possible to add [id5] => "val_5" to all instances of [sub_sub_1] without using loops and without knowing the value of [uid_1] and [sub_2]?

Comment: What's the problem with using a loop?

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = [
  'uid_1' => [
    'sub_1' => [
      'sub_sub_1' => [ 'id1' => 'val_1', 'id2' => 'val_2' ]
    ],
    'sub_2' => [
      'sub_sub_1' => [ 'id1' => 'val_1', 'id2' => 'val_2' ],
      'sub_sub_2' => [ 'id3' => 'val_3', 'id4' => 'val_4' ]
    ]
  ],
  'uid_2' => [
    'sub_1' => [
      'sub_sub_1' => [ 'id1' => 'val_1', 'id3' => 'val_3' ]
    ],
  ]
];

$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
  new RecursiveArrayIterator($array),
  RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);
$iterator->setMaxDepth(2);

while ($it->valid()) {
  if ($it->key() === 'sub_sub_1') {
    $array[$it->getSubIterator(0)->key()][$it->getSubIterator(1)->key()]['sub_sub_1']['id5'] = 'val_5';
  }
  $it->next();
}

print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [uid_1] => Array
        (
            [sub_1] => Array
                (
                    [sub_sub_1] => Array
                        (
                            [id1] => val_1
                            [id2] => val_2
                            [id5] => val_5
                        )

                )

            [sub_2] => Array
                (
                    [sub_sub_1] => Array
                        (
                            [id1] => val_1
                            [id2] => val_2
                            [id5] => val_5
                        )

                    [sub_sub_2] => Array
                        (
                            [id3] => val_3
                            [id4] => val_4
                        )

                )

        )

    [uid_2] => Array
        (
            [sub_1] => Array
                (
                    [sub_sub_1] => Array
                        (
                            [id1] => val_1
                            [id3] => val_3
                            [id5] => val_5
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Notes:

The `RecursiveArrayIterator` visits every top node of the array. The `RecursiveIteratorIterator` wraps the `RecursiveArrayIterator` and will visit every node of the array, not just the top nodes. And `setMaxDepth` makes sure we do not waste time visiting nodes more than three level deep.

We iterate, check for the key being 'sub_sub_1', and if true, we grab the parent path parts with `getSubIterator->key` calls. And then we just create the key and assign the value.

Answer (score 0):

Since You mentioned *The array is much bigger*, Loop may be needed.

```
    <?php
    $mainArray = array (
        "uid_1" => array (
            "sub_1" => array (
                "sub_sub_1" => array (
                    "id1" => "val_1",
                    "id2" => "val_2"
                )
                ),
            "sub_2" => array (
                "sub_sub_1" => array (
                    "id1" => "val_1",
                    "id2" => "val_2"
                ),
                "sub_sub_2" => array (
                    "id3" => "val_3",
                    "id4" => "val_4"
                )
            )
        )
    );

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r( $mainArray );
    echo "</pre>";



    foreach($mainArray["uid_1"] as $key=>$val){
        
        //$val (Arrays with index 'sub_1', 'sub_2' etc.)
        //Get array with index 'sub_sub_1' & Assign a New Value with key `id5`.

        $mainArray["uid_1"][$key]['sub_sub_1']["id5"] = "val_5";


    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r( $mainArray );
    echo "</pre>";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
<?php
$mainArray = array(
    "uid_1" => array(
        "sub_1" => array(
            "sub_sub_1" => array(
                "id1" => "val_1",
                "id2" => "val_2"
            )
        ),
        "sub_2" => array(
            "sub_sub_1" => array(
                "id1" => "val_1",
                "id2" => "val_2"
            ),
            "sub_sub_2" => array(
                "id3" => "val_3",
                "id4" => "val_4"
            )
        )
    )
);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($mainArray);
echo "</pre>";

foreach ($mainArray["uid_1"] as $key => $val) {

    // Check if 'sub_sub_1' exists before trying to access it
    if (isset($mainArray["uid_1"][$key]['sub_sub_1'])) {
        // Get array with index 'sub_sub_1' & Assign a New Value with key `id5`.
        $mainArray["uid_1"][$key]['sub_sub_1']["id5"] = "val_5";
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($mainArray);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: This is not likely to be a fully implemented solution because your are hardcoding the access to `uid_1` -- this should actually be another `foreach()`. Asker says: `without knowing the value of [uid_1] and [sub_2]`

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother trying to make a simple task more complicated. Using functions to iterate is likely to take longer and be harder to understand.

Use two nested loops which modify the data sets by reference and unconditionally push your desired associative element where required.

Even if a data set (subarray) doesn't have a `sub_sub_1` level, this script will create the level and safely push the required element into it.  If this is not the desired behavior, then you should provide a more representative sample input array and express how this fringe case should be handled.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/jKL9Y))

```
foreach ($array as &$uids) {
    foreach ($uids as &$subs) {
        $subs['sub_sub_1']['id5'] = 'val_5';
    }
}
var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'uid_1' => 
  array (
    'sub_1' => 
    array (
      'sub_sub_1' => 
      array (
        'id1' => 'val_1',
        'id2' => 'val_2',
        'id5' => 'val_5',
      ),
    ),
    'sub_2' => 
    array (
      'sub_sub_1' => 
      array (
        'id1' => 'val_1',
        'id2' => 'val_2',
        'id5' => 'val_5',
      ),
      'sub_sub_2' => 
      array (
        'id3' => 'val_3',
        'id4' => 'val_4',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'uid_2' => 
  array (
    'sub_1' => 
    array (
      'sub_sub_1' => 
      array (
        'id1' => 'val_1',
        'id3' => 'val_3',
        'id5' => 'val_5',
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```